# My UITableView won't scroll up as my UIScrollView does

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to create a "sticky scrollable header" above my `tableView` that collapses only halfway when scrolled up. I want the `tableView` to scroll separately but also to scroll up as my `scrollView` does. 
Here is what it currently looks like: 
[image]

In the next screen shot, you'll notice green. That is the background of the `scrollView` once I've scrolled up all the way (I'd like the dark gray and status view to remain in view at all times). I'd like the `tableView` to scroll up and cover that green but if I remove the `contentSize height` on the `scrollView`, it won't scroll! [image]

Here is what my storyboard and constraints look like.
[image][image]

What am I missing? Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Did you know that UITableView inherits from UIScrollView?  It can be difficult to control nested scrollViews, it might be easier to put your header at the table view and then control it appropriately.

Comment: @chelsiamia-Can I see How you managed it in code ?